# Discrete Math induction: The correct answer is 354162, but what are the steps to get to this answer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Got this question wrong, so I'm reviewing this question so I can understand this problem. I'm confused as to how to get the answer $3,5,4,1,6,2$ individually in that particular order.

Theorem $5.1.1$. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\quad 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$

The following sentences are enumerated. Put them in order as presented in the lesson material to create a proof of Theorem $5.1.1$. that uses an induction argument. Enter your answer as a $6$ digit integer. (For example, $123456$ is in a valid format for an answer, but it is incorrect.)

Inductive step: Assume that $P(n)$ is true, that is equation $(5.1)$ holds for some nonnegative integer $n$.

So it follows by induction that $P(n)$  is true for all nonnegative $n$.

We use induction.

Base case: $P(0)$ is true, because both sides of equation $(5.1)$ equal zero when $n = 0$.

The induction hypothesis $P(n)$ will be equation $(5.1)$.
Then adding $n + 1$ to both sides of the equation implies that

$\begin{align}
1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n + (n + 1) &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + (n + 1)\\
&= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} \quad \text{(by simple algebra)}
\end{align}$

which proves $P(n + 1)$.

Comment: You won't get TeX-like math formatting by writing "LaTeX:" in front of the math. (We don't even use LaTeX, but a Javascript-based lookalike called MathJax.) Instead, you need to use dollar signs. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for loads of examples.

Comment: @Arthur, it seems copy/pasted from an editor where math were written correctly but the paste operation didn't handle the latex part well it seems when I edited it.